# How to emliminate duplicates among AWK search patterns using AWK and/or SED

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following file called x.txt (excerpt only):

```
exMap( "0Ba|Mtm|Mtm","Variable Expenses","Accounting & Legal" )
exMap( "gn C[hu]|gn C[hu]|ent Ca","Variable Expenses","Bank – Charges" )
exMap( "t m|e Fee|^Deb|A\/C|hly pr|ged Ov|^Visa","Fixed Expenses","Bank – Charges" )
exMap( "ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|ATM|^Fix C|R US","Variable Expenses","Bank – Withdrawals" )
exMap( "Acci","Variable Expenses","Business – ACC" )
exMap( "use St$|Pgg","Variable Expenses","Business – Miscellaneous" )
exMap( "utd$|^Ellm|^Ellm|a Cy|^Stihl|^Stihl|a Mow","Variable Expenses","Business – Repairs & Maintenance" )
exMap( "Nzp","Fixed Expenses","Business Services – Mail" )
exMap( "0Ki|^K S","Fixed Expenses","Business – Storage" )
exMap( "2 C|2 C|40D|Tor|Tor|Tor|e of B|^Jay|^Luk|ll J|ty AP|le Au|eemi|eemi|eemi|^N[Zz] S|^N[Zz] S|s The J|P[Bb] T|P[Bb] T|P[Bb] T|mTo|deme|deme|deme|deme|deme|deme","Variable Expenses","Capex" )
exMap( "90C","Variable Expenses","Christian to Crewcut" )
exMap( "10E","Variable Expenses","Christian to Edorne" )
exMap( "0.0Ch|0.0Ch","Variable Expenses","Edorne to Christian" )
exMap( "lyt|-J|lyt|y Ha|NZA|^NZ T|^NZ T|^NZ T|^NZ T|^NZ T|^NZ T|^NZ T|acle Boo","Variable Expenses","Education" )
exMap( "weat|Aca|weat|Aca|weat|^A A|^A A|^A A|^A A|^A A|^A A|^A A|weat","Fixed Expenses","Education" )
exMap( "ntac|0Tr|ntac","Fixed Expenses","Electricity" )
```

This file is comma separated and consists of three columns. The first column contains awk regex search patterns. Some of them are duplicates such as |Mtm| in the first or |ATM| in the 4th line for example. Is there a smart way to eliminate duplicates in the entire file and keep the pipe structure intact using awk and/or sed?

The desired output then for the first and fourth line would be:

```
exMap( "0Ba|Mtm","Variable Expenses","Accounting & Legal" )
exMap( "ATM|^Fix C|R US","Variable Expenses","Bank – Withdrawals" )
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat rem_dupes.sed
s/\(|[^|]*|\?\"\?\)\1\+/\1/g
s/\(|\?[^|]*|\"\?\)\1\+/\1/g
s/\(\([a-z][^|]*\)|[^"]*\)|\2/\1/g
s/\(\([a-z0-9][^|]*\)|\?[^|]*\)|\1/\1/
s/\(\([a-z]*|\)[^|]*|\)\2/\1/
```

```
$ sed -f rem_dupes.sed input_file
exMap( "0Ba|Mtm","Variable Expenses","Accounting & Legal" )
exMap( "gn C[hu]|ent Ca","Variable Expenses","Bank – Charges" )
exMap( "t m|e Fee|^Deb|A\/C|hly pr|ged Ov|^Visa","Fixed Expenses","Bank – Charges" )
exMap( "ATM|^Fix C|R US","Variable Expenses","Bank – Withdrawals" )
exMap( "Acci","Variable Expenses","Business – ACC" )
exMap( "use St$|Pgg","Variable Expenses","Business – Miscellaneous" )
exMap( "utd$|^Ellm|a Cy|^Stihl|a Mow","Variable Expenses","Business – Repairs & Maintenance" )
exMap( "Nzp","Fixed Expenses","Business Services – Mail" )
exMap( "0Ki|^K S","Fixed Expenses","Business – Storage" )
exMap( "2 C|40D|Tor|e of B|^Jay|^Luk|ll J|ty AP|le Au|eemi|^N[Zz] S|s The J|P[Bb] T|mTo|deme","Variable Expenses","Capex" )
exMap( "90C","Variable Expenses","Christian to Crewcut" )
exMap( "10E","Variable Expenses","Christian to Edorne" )
exMap( "0.0Ch","Variable Expenses","Edorne to Christian" )
exMap( "lyt|-J|y Ha|NZA|^NZ Tcle Boo","Variable Expenses","Education" )
exMap( "weat|Aca|^A A","Fixed Expenses","Education" )
exMap( "ntac|0Tr","Fixed Expenses","Electricity" )
```

`s/\(|[^|]*|\?\"\?\)\1\+/\1/g` - Using grouping and back referencing, match and add to buffer group `\1` anything between two pipes `|` the second of which may or may not be present `\?` or a double quote `"` which again may or may not be present while the first pipe must be present. Everything that matched within the group is then repeated and added outside the grouping to be excluded. If the pattern of a duplicated match is found with the back reference `\1`, it is excluded only retaining the original match which is then returned in the replacement as back refence `\1`

`s/\(|\?[^|]*|\"\?\)\1\+/\1/g` - As above, grouping and back referencing is used but this time makes the initial pipe `|` optional while the second must be present.

`s/\(\([a-z][^|]*\)|[^"]*\)|\2/\1/g` - Nested grouping is used here to match a  specific pattern within the needed group. This grouping anf nested allows us to match duplicates that appear in a staggered sequence such as `lyt|-J|lyt|`

`s/\(\([a-z0-9][^|]*\)|\?[^|]*\)|\1/\1/` - As above, but this will also target integers, staggered duplicates.

`s/\(\([a-z]*|\)[^|]*|\)\2/\1/` - This is to clean up the final staggered duplicates found using nested grouping.

Comment: Thanks HatLess this works! I am trying to rap my mind around your code as I am not too familiar with sed apart from basic tutorials. Do you mind elaborating on what each line does?

Comment: @ChristianHick Please check edit

Comment: Thanks HatLess.